# Creating a 2D array dynamically using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, 2d, variable-assignment

```
// Trying to create 2D array dynamically using pointers

#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main()
{
    int *pool, **pool2, r = 3, c = 4;  /* r and c corresponds to rows and columns respectively */

    pool = (int *)calloc((r * c), sizeof(int)); /* creating all the blocks of int of 2D array*/
    pool2 = (int **)calloc(r, sizeof(int *));  /* using double pointers same as the number of rows with a thought of storing base addresses of each row*/

    int count = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= (r - 1); k++)
    {
        pool2[k][0] = &pool[count]; /* my query here : Since pool is of (int *) type, pool2 (being a double pointer) should be able to store the address of pool.*/

     // pool2[k] = &pool[count]; /* <------ BUT This WORKS FINE (after un-commenting)... instead of the above line !! */

        for (int m = 0; m <= (c - 1); m++)
        {
            printf("pool2[%d][%d] = %d\n", k, m, pool2[k][m]);
        }

        count += c; /* count increases to give the address of first block of the row (using &pool[count])*/
    }
    
    free(pool);
    free(pool2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

pool2[k][0] = &pool[count];
```

Why is the double pointer (`pool2`) not able to store the address of 'pointer to int'.

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Did you read the comments in the code ??
i did not ask to debug my code, the output warning was just to give an idea.. of course i searched about that warning message and tried to read other topics and questions related to it.
i asked a specific thing here which i might be missing as a concept probably.
That's why i specifically created an account just to ask this question.

This was my very first question on this site, maybe my way was wrong.. but at least try to get an idea about what was being actually asked in the first place.
Thank you for commenting though.

Answer (score 0):

The RHS `&pool[count]` returns an address.  It's the address of the `count` slot in the `pool` array.  The LHS `pool2[k][0]` is a reference to an integer slot. The compiler is correctly stating that you are trying to assign a pointer to an integer.

Comment: Hmm.. i thought that `pool2[k][0]` should also correspond to the value of the first slot of `pool2` array. 
Maybe to avoid confusion, i should use pointer de-refrencing to denote the exact slot for assigning any value or address to it.